# How can I echo minutes since midnight in any timezone using the date command on OS X?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, date, command-line

Here's what isn't working:

```
> echo $(( ($(date +%s) - $(date +%s -d$(date +%Y-%m-%d))) / 60 ))
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

I've also tried:

```
> echo $(date +%s -f%Y-%m-%d $(date +%Y-%m-%d))
```

The following works, but only with a fixed UTC offset that will break during standard time:

```
> echo $[ ( ( $(date "+%s") - 28800 ) % 86400 ) / 60 ]
```

Reference: [OS X date manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/date.1.html)

Comment: What do you expect the `-d` option to do?

Comment: @cdarke set the date to midnight of today, in seconds, to subtract from now seconds.

Comment: So it does. How would you recommend calculating seconds at midnight to subtract from seconds now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your first attempt is that you're trying to apply a gnu date option to the BSD date that's on OSX. This has caught me out a lot as I've tried to make scripts compatible between both platforms.

One way is:

```
seconds_now=$(date +%s)
seconds_midnight=$(date -j -f'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' "$(date +%Y-%m-%d) 00:00:00" +%s)
minutes_now=$(((seconds_now - seconds_midnight) / 60))
```

You have to use the full format for the time, otherwise date takes the actual hours, minutes and seconds of the current time, which is not what you want.

Another way is:

Use date +%z to get the offset from UTC, and apply it to the number of minutes past midnight on the day.

```
offset=$(date +%z) # get TZ offset as [+-]<HH><MM> - for *now*
sign=${offset:0:1} # get sign
hours=${offset:1:2} # get hours
mins=${offset:3:2} # get minutes
minoff=$((10#$hours * 60 + 10#$mins)) # offset in minutes from UTC
from_midnight_utc_mins=$((($(date +%s) % 86400) / 60))
from_midnight_local=$(($from_midnight_utc_mins $sign $minoff))
```

It's seriously gack, though.

> I use `10#` for all the numbers in the `minoff` calculation to prevent the case where two digit numbers with a leading 0 are interpreted as octal, which can yield miscalculations/errors.

Comment: Is it possible to ignore UTC offset altogether and just subtract system date (now()) from system date midnight (y-m-d)?

Comment: I've added a solution using `date -j -f` and reordered the answers as it's definitely shorter. I have not tested this when there's a time change (e.g. summer time/winter time)

Comment: Nice! One liner: `echo $((($(date +%s) - $(date -j -f'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' "$(date +%Y-%m-%d) 00:00:00" +%s)) / 60))`

Comment: I tested it using a sample date of 2015-03-29 (TZ=Europe/Dublin, has summer time transition at 1am), and at 5am it reports 240 minutes since midnight, which is the correct number of minutes since midnight in that case. If you want just the number of minutes and don't care about DST transitions then @chepner's answer is an easier one to use

Answer (score 5):

The number of minutes (or seconds) since midnight can be computed directly from a time alone.

```
echo $(( $(date "+10#%H * 60 + 10#%M") ))  # Minutes since midnight
echo $(( $(date "+(10#%H * 60 + 10#%M) * 60 + 10#%S") ))  # Seconds since midnight
```

Note that this requires only minimal support from `date`, so will work with either GNU or BSD `date`.

This works by having `date` output a string which can be passed directly to the shell's arithmetic expression construct.

Thanks to Petesh for pointing out the need to force numbers with leading zeros to be treated as decimal.

Comment: Works when there isn't a DST transition. In a typical summer time transition (e.g. +1 hour @ 1am), it would report 5am as being 300 minutes after midnight, while it's actually only 240 hours after midnight.

Comment: Is there a way to get "echo $(( $(date "+(10#%H * 60 + 10#%M) * 60 + 10#%S") ))" into a variable? I've tried var=$(echo $(( $(date "+(10#%H * 60 + 10#%M) * 60 + 10#%S") ))) and a couple of other variants but no success.